# pagination in tiles in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, salesforcedx, lightning-design-system

I wanna create UI Like this, I wanna add Pagination in Tiles using LWC is it possible? and this Title of section is accordion it should be expandable/collapsible, when I click on > arrow, the below section will open with tiles and pagination[image]

Tile details
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do by simply passing 8 records to UI first time when they click next then you should update the next records in same variable and you can do this further. Same thing you can follow by decreasing the 8 when they click back button, but must check that we have 8 records or not. You can use below code for reference.

HTML code

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <template for:each={displayedTiles} for:item="tile">
            <div key={tile.id} class="tile">{tile.label}</div>
        </template>
    </div>
    <div class="pagination">
        <lightning-button-group>
            <lightning-button label="Previous" onclick={handlePrevious} disabled={disablePrevious}></lightning-button>
            <lightning-button label="Next" onclick={handleNext} disabled={disableNext}></lightning-button>
        </lightning-button-group>
    </div>
</template>
```

JS Code

```
import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';

export default class PaginationDemo extends LightningElement {
    @track tiles = []; // Array of all tiles
    @track displayedTiles = []; // Array of tiles to display
    @track currentPage = 1;
    @track pageSize = 8;
    
    connectedCallback() {
        // Initialize tiles data (20 tiles in this example)
        for (let i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
            this.tiles.push({ id: i, label: `Tile ${i}` });
        }
        // Initial display of tiles
        this.displayTiles();
    }
    
    displayTiles() {
        const startIndex = (this.currentPage - 1) * this.pageSize;
        const endIndex = startIndex + this.pageSize;
        this.displayedTiles = this.tiles.slice(startIndex, endIndex);
    }
    
    get disablePrevious() {
        return this.currentPage === 1;
    }
    
    get disableNext() {
        return this.currentPage === Math.ceil(this.tiles.length / this.pageSize);
    }
    
    handlePrevious() {
        if (!this.disablePrevious) {
            this.currentPage--;
            this.displayTiles();
        }
    }
    
    handleNext() {
        if (!this.disableNext) {
            this.currentPage++;
            this.displayTiles();
        }
    }
}
```

Please let me know if you have any doubt

Comment: The thing is I am supposed to show 12 tiles on first page and I am not aware how many tiles we will have, because it depends on different scenarios, we might have 7 records in some, in some scenarios we might have 20 records, so will this code work for that?

Comment: @Nia yes you can get the size of records by using length and you can set that in for loop. you can initialize by the length of records and it will work

Comment: and I wanna add employee ID and name in tiles, I mean these tiles have this data inside it, so how do i do it? I have added data tile on question

Comment: @Nia for that you can use an array of objects. and integrate on that array and use object properties to display the employee id and name.  [{Id:'1', Name:'A'},{Id:'2', Name:'B'},...]

Comment: can you show please

Comment: @Nia you need to pass data into [{Id:'1', Name:'A'},{Id:'2', Name:'B'},...] this manner. it will work. You should try this first. I can only tell the approach and help you to debug your code but I can not write the entire code

Comment: i have completed this requirement, thank you

Comment: Thanks for letting me know.